# Android Pending Intent to start service

Tags: android, service, android-notifications

So I have a service, in the `onCreate()` I setup 3 pending intents to start the same service, each having different extra data to specify the action. I'm creating a notification, and I want to use one pending intent as the click action, one as the dismiss action, and the third is for an alarm.

```
        Intent iCancel = new Intent(this, BootService.class);
        Intent iAlarm = new Intent(this, BootService.class);
        Intent iDismiss = new Intent(this, BootService.class);

        // each will have actions
        iAlarm.putExtra(INTENT_ACTION, INTENT_ALARM_FIRED);
        iCancel.putExtra(INTENT_ACTION, INTENT_CANCEL);
        iDismiss.putExtra(INTENT_ACTION, INTENT_DISMISS);

        PendingIntent piCancel = PendingIntent.getService(
                this,
                0,
                iCancel,
                Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

        mPiAlarm = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, iAlarm, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

        PendingIntent piDismiss = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, iDismiss, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

        mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_about)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentIntent(piCancel)
                .setDeleteIntent(piDismiss);
```

The problem is all pending intents seem that have the same intent extra data, so when `onStartCommand` is launched no matter whether the notification was clicked or dismissed or neither, constant `INTENT_CANCEL` is received from `intent.getIntExtra(INTENT_ACTION)`

I believe it has something to do with the flags used in `PendingIntent.getService()`, i'm confused about which to use. I've tried using `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`, and `UPDATE_CURRENT`, neither seem to fix the issue but the result is different, I receive constant `INTENT_ALARM_FIRED` for every action.

How can I get each pending intent to have its own intent extra data?

**Solution**

I discovered an exact warning about this scenario right in the `PendingIntent` doc. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

just changed my request codes and it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with Intents being considered the same. See [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) for more information.

One way to get around this would be to just vary the requestCode for each Intent. (The 2nd parameter in the `getService` call)